# Mute button for InDesign EPUB music

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, epub

I'm creating a fixed design EPUB for a client.

They would like background music to be present whilst the book is open. I've added an MP3 to the master page within InDesign, but the controls are limiting.

Is it possible to add a mute button? The EPUB will be viewed via an iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a combination of two buttons (play/pause) both set as that when one is clicked it hides the other. And also of course play/pause the sound:
[image]

[The epub here:](http://dl.free.fr/kxYCWzrcw)